# Firestore - How can I add the Document ID and their data in my state?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my database from Firestore, each User has a sub-collection called Apps. I need to add in my state the id of each document and their data. I know how to add the data in my state, with the following code `setApps(data.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))` and I know how to get the ID of each document `data.docs.map(doc => console.log(doc.id, doc.data()))`.

But how can I add in my state `doc.id` and `doc.data()` at the same time?

Thanks for your help.

```js
function AppList() {
   
    const [apps, setApps] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const db = firebase.firestore()
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

            if (user != null) {
                var uid = user.uid
                const data = await db
                .collection('Users').doc(uid)
                .collection('Apps').get()
                
                //Add the data of each doc in my state
                setApps(data.docs.map( doc => doc.data()));
    
                //Get the document ID
                data.docs.map(doc => 
                    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data())
                );
            }
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <Row gutter={{ xs: 8, sm: 16, md: 24, lg: 32 }}> 
        {apps.map(app => (
            <Col className="gutter-row" span={100}>
                <Card
                style={{ width: 300, marginTop: 16}}
                actions={[
                    <Button type="default" size='middle'>
                    <Link to={app.appName}>    
                        <EditOutlined /> 
                        <span> Edit the app </span>
                    </Link>
                    </Button>,
                    ]}>
                    <Meta
                    title= {app.appName}
                    description={app.description}
                    />
                </Card>   
            </Col>
        ))}
        </ Row>  
    );
}
```

Comment: React hook useReducer can help you https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the solution

```
setApps(data.docs.map(doc => {return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id} }));
```

Comment: Great solution, and of course this can be also written like the following;
`setApps(data.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));`

Answer (score 0):

Besides that, you can add this if you use setState

```
initialData.forEach((doc) => {
  this.setState({
    data: [...this.state.data,{...doc.data(), id: doc.id }],
  });
});
```